# how to turn an image sideways or upside-down?

Tags: android

I have a custom view and i am using onDraw() to draw onto my canvas. I am drawing an image on this canvas.

I want to turn the image upside down kinda like flip on a horizontal line as a reference. This is not the same as rotating the image by 180 deg or -180 deg.

Likewise, i want to mirror or flip sidways i.e with a vertical line as it's pivot or reference. Again this is not the same as the canvas.rotate() provides.

I am wondering how to do it. Should i use a matrix or does canvas provide any method to do it like that of a "rotate".

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot do it with Canvas directly.  You will need to actually modify the Bitmap (using Matrix) before drawing it.  Luckily, it's a very simple code to do this:

```
public enum Direction { VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL };

/**
    Creates a new bitmap by flipping the specified bitmap
    vertically or horizontally.
    @param src        Bitmap to flip
    @param type       Flip direction (horizontal or vertical)
    @return           New bitmap created by flipping the given one
                      vertically or horizontally as specified by
                      the <code>type</code> parameter or
                      the original bitmap if an unknown type
                      is specified.
**/
public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap src, Direction type) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    if(type == Direction.VERTICAL) {
        matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
    }
    else if(type == Direction.HORIZONTAL) {
        matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    } else {
        return src;
    }

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Where I wanted a flipped image and was using setImageResource, I simply replaced with this: imageView.setImageBitmap(flip(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.someimage),Direction.HORIZONTAL));

Comment: I know this is very old, but this just saved my bacon. Thanks!

Comment: You're wrong in stating that this can't be done directly on `Canvas`. In fact, the method you're using to create a new `Bitmap` actually does it by creating a new `Canvas` and drawing on it from the source using the provided dimensions and matrix. For a custom view, doing this operation directly in `onDraw()` would be much more efficient for memory and processing.

Comment: @corsair992 What I said was that you can't simply rotate a canvas with existing image on it - you'll need to redraw the image.  I also provided a method for rotating the image - whether you put the code in onDraw or wherever else - is totally up to you.

Comment: @AleksG: The question was about drawing an image directly onto a `Canvas` in a custom view, in which case you can simply apply the matrix onto it directly at drawing time instead of having to waste extra memory/processing on creating a new `Bitmap`. Even if this is not done on each `onDraw()` callback, it's still an unnecessary and non-optimal operation.