# Android image captured orientation is wrong ( custom camera)

Tags: android, camera

i've been struggling with the problem below, i found some tutorials and made a custom camera with a SurfaceView as a preview holder.
I'm mainly concerned for the front Camera.
Now when i take an image while the preview works fine the image is being saved with a wrong rotation in my SD card.

Below are the main two functions. Setup of the camera and the take picture.

```
*private void setUpCamera(Camera c) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degree = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degree = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degree = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degree = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degree = 270;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            // frontFacing
            rotation = (info.orientation + degree) % 360;
            rotation = (360 - rotation) % 360;
        } else {
            // Back-facing
            rotation = (info.orientation - degree + 360) % 360;
        }

        c.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);
        Parameters params = c.getParameters();

        List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (focusModes != null) {
            if (focusModes
                    .contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            }
        }

        params.setRotation(rotation);
        c.setParameters(params);
    }*


private void takeImage() {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

            private File imageFile;

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                try {
                    // convert byte array into bitmap
                    Bitmap loadedImage = null;

                    loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);

                    // rotate Image
                    Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
                    rotateMatrix.postRotate(rotation);
                    loadedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage, 0, 0,loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(),rotateMatrix, false);

                    //create folder if it doesnt exists
                    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    File folder = null;
                    if (state.contains(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                        folder = new File(Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Squote");
                    } else {
                        folder = new File(Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Squote");
                    }
                    boolean success = true;
                    if (!folder.exists()) {
                        success = folder.mkdirs();
                    }
                    if (success) {
                        // Create a media file name
                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                        imageFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath()
                                + File.separator
                                + "IMG_"
                                + timeStamp
                                + ".jpg");

                        imageFile.createNewFile();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image Not saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    // save image into gallery
                    loadedImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);

                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    fout.write(ostream.toByteArray());
                    fout.close();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN,System.currentTimeMillis());
                    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    //release camera and return image
                    releaseCamera();
                    Intent intentMessage = new Intent();
                    intentMessage.putExtra("imageUri", imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intentMessage);
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

On the `rotate image` part of the code if i put `270` it shows up correct BUT i'm having another issue there. The image is not the same as the preview but it's mirrored. I think also that a fixed 270 value is not a solution as it messes up the back camera or the portrait pictures.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue, it's how the front-facing camera works. Even if you take a picture with your phone's camera app it will be flipped when saved. You can implement a method to flip the image vertically if that is the result you are trying to get.

Comment: You can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609695/how-to-turn-an-image-sideways-or-upside-down) link to help you with the flipping of the image.